# Accordion headings cuts off to second line on collapsing a accordion heading (used acf repeater)

Tags: php, loop

```
<div class="container">
        <?php if( have_rows('director_information') ): ?>
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist">

            <div class="row">
                <?php $i=1; while ( have_rows('director_information') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <div class="card d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="heading-<?php echo $i; ?>">

                                <button class="btn btn-link px-5 py-4" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                    <?php if( get_field('director_image') ): ?>
                                        <img src="<?php the_field('director_image'); ?>" />
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <p class="pt-3 mb-1 font-weight-bold"><?php the_sub_field('director_name'); ?></p>
                                    <small><?php the_sub_field('director_designation'); ?></small>
                                </button>

                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="collapse-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="col-md-12 collapse <?php if ($i==1) { echo 'show'; } ?>" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <?php the_sub_field('director_details'); ?>
                </div>
                <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>            
            </div>

            </div>          
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: The issue would be with whatever script your using to create the accordion functionality. How are you doing this?

Comment: Only script that I have added is the bootstrap 4.1 js and jquery 3.1